# .NET dll calling in MATLAB

Tags: .net, vb.net, matlab

I have a public .dll (KRcc64.dll) created by a manufacturer using .NET for interfacing any code with his machine .

It has a class called "Commu" for making TCP/IP connection with the machine .

Parameters are :

TCP or COM

IP address

port

time-out

I wrote a small code using VB.Net to test it & it is working perfectly .

Here is the VB code :
'

Module Program

```
Sub sample_of_command()

    'connect to the controller
    Dim comm As KRcc.Commu

    Try

        Console.Write("connecting . . . ")

        comm = New KRcc.Commu("TCP 127.0.0.1 10300 3000")

        Console.WriteLine("done")

    Catch

        Console.WriteLine("Can't connect")

        Exit Sub

    End Try
```

The issue which i faced it is trying to use this .NET with MATLAB and always getting immediate response from MATLAB as followings :

Message: can't connect TCP/IP
Source: krcc64

I am using the following MATLAB code

asm = NET.addAssembly('C:**\krcc64.dll')

Comm_Port = KRcc.Commu('TCP 127.0.0.1 10300')

Please your support !

Comment: Since one year ago and still unable to know what is the reason for MATLAB not being able to use this .NET library.